# sliding doesn't work only in mobile android chrome. (Vue)

Tags: html, css, vue.js, slider

I'm beginner level Vue.js developer.

I found some code to slide menu to left (horizontally) as below.
(When DIV tag width is bigger than device width, you can slide it to left to see more.)
It works just fine only except android chrome (Nothing moves...).

[screenshot of site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmEhd.png)
Would anybody know how to fix this issue? Please kindly help.

my code is as below

```
    <div class="roomNav">
      <div class="roomNavInner">
        <div v-for="(r, index) in roomList" :key="index">
          <div class="roomNavInnerDiv" @click="selected=index" :class="{highlight:selected == index}" v-scroll-to="`#roomType${index}`">{{r[0].roomType}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

```
.roomNav{
  position: fixed;
  top: 130px;
  height: 62.5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 10;
}
.roomNavInner{
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:62.5px; 
  max-height: 100vw; 
  margin:0;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-62.5px); 
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-62.5px); 
  -o-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-62.5px); 
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-62.5px); 
  transform:rotate(-90deg) translateY(-62.5px); // 
  -ms-transform-origin:right top;
  -webkit-transform-origin:right top;
  -o-transform-origin:right top;
  -moz-transform-origin:right top;
  transform-origin:right top;
  padding:40px 0 150px 0; 
}
.roomNavInnerDiv{
  display:block;
  padding:auto 5px;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(62.5px); 
  -ms-transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(62.5px); 
  -o-transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(62.5px); 
  -moz-transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(62.5px); 
  transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(62.5px); 
  -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
  -ms-transform-origin: right top;
  -moz-transform-origin: right top;
  -o-transform-origin: right top;
  transform-origin: right top;
  width:100px; 
  height:35px; 
  margin:80px 13.75px; 
  color: #4a4a4a;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'NotoSansCJKkr-Regular';
  border-radius: 18px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px rgba(0,0,0,.25); 
  line-height: 35px;
}

.roomNavInnerDiv.highlight { 
  background-color: rgb(85, 31, 255);
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem with Chrome for Android. 
This is my settings and a free slide stopped working.
{
    type      : "slide",
    drag      : "free",
    width     : "100%",
    autoWidth : true,
    arrows    : false,          
    pagination: false,
  }